# how to remove custom tag in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

i want to remove a custom tag for example

```
<figure class="promo-box vmig slideshow ga-event" data-ga_event-category="Slideshow" data-ga_event-action="SS-Promo-Impression" data-ga_event-label="SS: Newborn Baby Health: 8 Woes From Cradle Cap And Colic To Whooping Cough" data-ga_event-noninteraction="true">  
 <figcaption>  
 </figcaption> 
</figure>
```

this whole tag from jsoup element i have used

```
    document.select(".promo-box").remove();
    document.select("figure ").remove();
```

but its not working, also not working for `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

its little bit tricky..

replace your tag with div that or any other html tag you dont want to use and remove that..

in your case it will be like this

```
document.select("figure").tagName("div");
document.select("div").remove();
```